# Need HTML Page as response from one application to another application

Tags: java, .net

we need HTML Page as response from one application  to another application. how to access to different language based websites . is it possible to access via webservices? I dont know pleas help

Comment: standard way is to just exchange data between apps and not full translated pages. You should consider REST backed by JSON or XML transport format.

Comment: Could you please explain in details what you need ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to pass HTML content between applications. This is essentially how browsers work.

Below is an example of REST service that sends the content of an index.html file I have in my path:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@RestController
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/webpage", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String webpage()  throws IOException {
        String html = FileCopyUtils.copyToString(new FileReader("index.html"));
        return html;
    }
}
```

If you deploy this service and go in a browser and lookup the address

```
http://localhost:8080/webpage
```

it will return and render the html page. If you use a rest client and call GET on the same address, it will return the actual html of that page.

The example is using Spring Boot to automatically configure the web service with some defaults. You can learn more about Spring Boot at the [spring.io](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) website

If you need help setting up a small Maven project with the service I showed you, just leave a comment addressed to me and I'll help you out.

**EDIT** jsp pages need to pass through the rendering process it normally does when you request a page from a browser. This means that you can use a simple REST client to request pages from you application.

I suggest using [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html) as it is simple to use. Just make a call to the url you have deployed (which includes the path to the jsp page, like http://example-domain.com/index.jsp) and it should return the generated HTML.

See the example in the link for Unirest

Comment: hi thank u. one more doubt, i'm having index.jsp page in webapps folder. how to give path in file reader.

Comment: @TELMILA, added an update with regards to your doubt.